# How to get data from REST API using a graphql

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql

How to get data from REST API using a graphql query

How to get data from REST API using a graphql

Comment: What language do u use?

Comment: Graphql - Java script

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it is easier to make queries to a REST API in the traditional RESTful manner and GraphQl only to GraphQL. However, I'm going to assume that in your case, you have a GraphQL server running and you are trying to query a public API that is only available using REST.  There are a few different ways to do this, but both require some knowledge of the data schema which you are querying.

If you want to do this client-side, you can make a typical REST query using axios, fetch, got, or whatever other HTTP agent you prefer and incorporate that data in the UI with your GraphQL data. [Apollo Client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/local-state/local-resolvers#querying-local-state) offers an option to distinguish data not from the GraphQL API by including `@client` on specific fields in your query. This helps maintain the cache and keep your global schema in sync.

If you already have a GraphQL server running, you need to define a custom schema and resolvers to match the data fetched from the REST API. Here is a very small example using `express-graphql` to create a GraphQL endpoint using the SpaceX REST API.

```
const {
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLBoolean,
  GraphQLList,
  GraphQLSchema
} = require('graphql');

// Launch Type
const LaunchType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Launch',
  fields: () => ({
    flight_number: { type: GraphQLInt },
    mission_name: { type: GraphQLString },
    launch_year: { type: GraphQLString },
    launch_date_local: { type: GraphQLString },
    launch_success: { type: GraphQLBoolean }
  })
});

const LaunchQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
 name: 'LaunchQueryType',
 fields: {
  launches: {
   type: new GraphQLList(LaunchType),
    resolve(parent, args) {
     return axios
     .get('https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/launches')
     .then(res => res.data);
     }
    }
   }
});

module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({query: LaunchQuery});
```

You could then incorporate this with your other resolvers to complete your GraphQL endpoint.

Comment: This is great, but what if you wanted to send an request object to the API. Can you share some references for the same

Answer (score 0):

Option 1)
Use some Graphql server:
Apollo Layering GraphQL on top of REST
Details here https://www.apollographql.com/blog/backend/layering-graphql-on-top-of-rest/
Or Hasura has ability to setup GraphQL to fetch data from REST APIs

Option 2)
For coding yourself, Use EasyManage (Free Plan) to generate Free GraphQL APIs and REST APIs on required schema and internally customize graphql resolver to fetch data from REST API: example here:

GrpahQL Resolver:

```
    @QueryMapping
public List<DgproductinventoryviewTblRec> DgproductinventoryviewTblRecViewAll()  
    throws Exception 
    {   
    List<DgproductinventoryviewTblRec> DgproductinventoryviewTblRecList = new ArrayList<DgproductinventoryviewTblRec>(); 
    try { 
 
        DgproductinventoryviewTblRec1Repository.findAll().forEach(DgproductinventoryviewTblRecList::add); 
         
 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        System.out.println("Error: Exception:  "+e.getMessage()); 
        //e.printStackTrace(System.out); 
        throw new Exception(e.getMessage()); 
    } 
    return DgproductinventoryviewTblRecList; 
}
```

Customize above resolver as per below to fetch from REST API (Note: Class names are different, this is code suggestion only):

```
        //Get from 1st Db
        InventoryTblRec1Repository.findAll().forEach(InventoryTblRecList::add); 
        //InventoryTblRec1Repository.findByColumnName(columnVal).forEach(InventoryTblRecList::add); 

        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //Get from 2nd Db
        String get_state = "http://127.0.0.1:9085/emdbrest/inventory/ViewAll";
        WebClient webClient1 = WebClient.builder().baseUrl(get_state)
        .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).build();


        Mono<List<InventoryTblRec>> response =
        webClient1.get()
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<InventoryTblRec>>() {});
        
        List<InventoryTblRec> getListInventoryTblRec = response.block();

        getListInventoryTblRec.forEach(InventoryTblRecList::add);
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The code can be downloaded then customized and packaged/run as jar graphql service.